# regex on the shell?

Tags: bash, regex

I wanted to do some simple regex so i am trying to get the 16. I tried grep but i dont see how to write \1 or $1 to only output the capture data and i tried sed but i think i did it wrong due to escaping i am not familiar with. Anyways my regex is this

```
(\d+)\%\s*/$
```

The string is

```
# df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda             15997904   2404540  12943248  16% /
tmpfs                   252456         0    252456   0% /lib/init/rw
tmpfs                   252456        36    252420   1% /dev/shm
```

and on this site the output is exactly what i want (move your mouse over to see group matches) http://regexr.com?2sd12

Answer (score 1):

awk is very well suited to this task:

```
df | awk 'NR > 1 {print $5, $6;}'
```

says skip the first line `NR > 1`  and then on all other lines print
the 5th and 6th whitespace separated fields. It yields:

```
65% /
1% /dev
1% /dev/shm
```

### added in response to comment:

The demo site didn't match your description, sorry. Although there are simpler ways to do this, here is the same chain with `tr` added so you have one more tool in your box:

```
df | awk 'NR > 1 {print $5;}' | tr -d '%'
```

and if you only wanted it for (e.g.) /dev/shm then:

```
df | awk '/\/dev\/shm$/ {print $5;}' | tr -d '%'
```

or root:

```
df | awk '/\/$/ {print $5;}' | tr -d '%'
```

Comment: I'm trying to get only the value and not the % sign so i can assign the int to a bash variable.

Comment: The first line is reported anyway in your version, it is better `df | awk 'NR > 1 { print $5, $6 }'`

Comment: instead of telling `awk` to filter for mount point, I think you should rather use `df /dev/shm`, etc  ...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using some tool to alter the output of `df`, you should simply use `df`'s `--output` option to limit the output to your needs:

```
df --output=pcent,target
```

To get only the %-values:

```
df --output=pcent | tail -n+2 | tr -d '[% ]'
```

To get the same for `/`:

```
df --output=pcent / | tail -n+2 | tr -d '[% ]'
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, [grep](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/1/grep)) prints the whole line matching a regexp, but you can tell it to print just the matching string with option `--only-matching`:

```
df -h | egrep --only-matching '[[:digit:]]+%' | tr -d '%'
```

Note that:

1. The grep/[egrep](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/1/egrep) regexp syntax is a bit different from the PERL-style regexp syntax that you posted.  In addition, there are differences between the regexp syntax supported by grep (called "POSIX basic regexp") and the one used in [egrep](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/1/egrep) (extended regexp).
2. There's no way to tell egrep to output a certain subexpression of the match: the whole match will be printed, including the `%` sign.  But you can strip it out with [tr](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/1/tr).

Comment: weird syntax, why cant i capture with multiple groups? maybe i should learn python or perl and do it from there :x

Comment: Just for fuss: you can have multiple capture groups in an _egrep_ regex, there is just no option to select which one to print; you always get the full match.

Comment: `grep -P` can use Perl-regexp syntax (but it's experimental, so probably doesn't work in all cases)

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, you can use Python to retrieve the disk usage.

The following code snippet will display the value at the first occurrence of the pattern (in your case *16*):

```
import subprocess
import re
print re.search('(\d+)% /', subprocess.Popen(["df"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]).group(1)
```

If you'd like to retrieve the values from each line, a little longer code would do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import subprocess
import re

p = subprocess.Popen(["df"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in p.stdout:
    usage = re.search('(\d+)% /', line.rstrip())
    if usage != None:
        print usage.group(1)
```

Basically it works the same way, just it reads the output line-by-line in contrast to the `Popen.communicate()` call that retrieves the whole output in one go.